# get value from FIRAuth swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an iOS app, which I use FirebaseAuth to authinticate my user with phone no, my back end API require to send a `_lastnotifiedusertoken` to it after authontication succeeded, bellow an image of returned value.

[Image of auth result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swUax.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this value from:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDToken(completion: { token, error in 
     print(token as Any)
}
```